# Как засунуть client_secret и token в .env

Tags: python, google-drive

У меня есть код из квикстарта по работе с API гугла

```
def auth() -> Credentials:
    scopes = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
    ]

    credentials = None

    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json',
                                                        scopes)
    if not credentials or not credentials.valid:
        if credentials and credentials.expired and credentials.refresh_token:
            credentials.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secret.json', scopes)
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(credentials.to_json())
    return credentials
```

Тут я получаю `client_secret.json` и `token.json`. Хотелось бы `client_secret` и `token` доставать из `.env` файла и, что важно, сохранять в `.env` файл. Проблема в том, что `.from_authorized_user_file` принимает файл, а в `.env` хранится словарь, типа `client_secret={...}`.

Как мне переписать этот код, чтобы все работало через `.env`?Встроенный метод `.to_json()` или дамп словаря в json не работает, он жалуется на файл, что логично

То есть так, чтобы я, например, мог импортировать конфигурацию, типа `from config import config` и передавать не файл, а сразу словарь `config.token` или `config.client_secret`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй конструкторы
`Credentials.from_authorized_user_info`
и
`InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config`
в которых вместо имени файла передается мапинг с параметрами.

В .env положить json, yml, или ещё что

```
{
"client_config": ....,
"token":.....
}
```

или toml

```
client_config.foo = ...
client_config.bar = ...

token.access = ...
token.refresh = ....
```

то как вы задумали не очень удобно читать из питона, а гонять в enviroment не безопасно.

Comment: Как лучше сделать? У меня есть config.py, в котором через pydantic я достаю переменные из .env и создаю объект Settings(). Через него и управляю всеми переменными, то есть можно обратиться config.token